# PHPSpec class construction per test

Tags: php, phpspec

I am looking for  a way to represent the following per test method in PHPSpec, each test needs a class constructor created like this

```
$config = new Config( 'path_to_config' );
$client = new SOAPService( $config );
$debtor = new Debtor( $client );
```

and then I can test something like

```
class DebtorSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
function it_has_method_getDebtor()
{
$debtor->getDebtor( '123' )->shouldReturn( TRUE );
}
}
```

how do I pass that kind of class constructor to phpspec?

Comment: If you're speccing the Debtor class, its collaborators (Config, SOAPService) should be either stubbed or mocked. How does your Debtor class look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `let()` method and call `beConstructedWith()` in it. Read it [here](http://www.phpspec.net/en/latest/manual/let-and-letgo.html).

CLASS

```
class Hello
{
    private $writer;

    public function __construct(Writer $write)
    {
        $this->write = $writer;
    }

    // You methods
}
```

SPEC

```
namespace spec;

use PhpSpec\ObjectBehavior;
use Markdown\Writer;

class HelloSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function let(Writer $writer)
    {
        $this->beConstructedWith($writer);
    }

    // Write your method test
}
```

Comment: I have tried that, but what I need is a way to have more than one constructor, I have Config, SOAP and a debtor class

Comment: You should stub or mock the collaborators of a class you're speccing and do not instantiate them.